# Cannot load RevoScaler

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I have just installed R evolution (Windows 7, 64 bit).

Immediately after loading, RStudio shows the following error:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'RevoScaleR', details:
>        call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
>        error: The evaluation period has expired

I checked the following:

1. `.libPaths()` gives the correct library path
2. `"RevoScaleR" %in% names(installed.packages()[1]) 
    #TRUE`

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There last line seems to give some insight...

> The evaluation period has expired.

Do you have a valid commercial license? If not, potentially there is your reason. If so, support should be your first stop.

To ensure you have either a free developer version or a paid commercial version, here are some links:

1. http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/01/microsoft-r-open.html
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/
3. https://www.microsoft.com/en/server-cloud/products/r-server/default.aspx

Comment: Hi Derek, thank you for your reply. Maybe I have got things wrong to begin with. I thought R enterprise has a free version. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Maybe, but maybe not.  It depends.  There are versions available for free for development.  I will edit my answer above with some links.

Answer (score 0):

RevoScaleR is now a Microsoft package. Install Microsoft R Client to use RevoScaleR. [Microsoft R Client with RevoScaleR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/r-server/r-client/what-is-microsoft-r-client)